# C++ gRPC thread number configuration

Tags: c++, grpc

Does gRPC server/client have any concept of thread pool for connections? That it is possible to reuse threads, pre-allocate threads, queue request on thread limit reached, etc.

If no, how does it work, is it just allocating/destroying a thread when it need, without any limitation and/or reuse? If yes, is it possible to configure it?

Answer (score 11):

It depends whether you are using sync or async API.
For a sync client, your RPC calls blocks the calling thread, so it is not really relevant. For a sync server, there is an internal threadpool handling all the incoming requests, you can use a `grpc::ResourceQuota` on a `ServerBuilder` to limit the max number of threads used by the threadpool.

For async client and server, gRPC uses `CompletionQueue` as a way for users to define their own threading model. A common way of building clients and servers is to use a user-provided threadpool to run `CompletionQueue::Next` in each thread. Then once it gets some tag from the `Next` call, you can cast it to a user-defined type and run some methods to proceed the state. In this case, the user has full control of threads being used.

Note gRPC does create some internal threads, but they should not be used for the majority of the rpc work.

Comment: I have checked `ResourceQuota`, I think it is only memory configuration? The only thing I found is`GRPC_ARG_MAX_CONCURRENT_STREAMS` that limits HTTP2 stream number.

Comment: It is a recent change I believe. See `ResourceQuota::SetMaxThreads`